# Data not saving on online server in WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress child theme, when I do changing on my local server the changing save, everything is perfect, but when I do the same code changing on my online theme the changing is saving in the PHP file but not effecting the display or front end and when I do inspect element on browser it is showing the old code like there is not the new code which I do save.

And also when change the name of the file e.g style.css as style2.css it effects the front end.

I have also done checking by different methods like plugins deactivation.

Comment: have you cleared your wordpress and browser cache ? NOPE? then try it.

Comment: I delete the browser cache, but how can i delete wordpress cache

Comment: if you have installed any plugin to enable cache then and then only you have to clear it, otherwise it's not needed.

Comment: No I have not installed any cache plugin.

Comment: Are you sure you have the child theme activated? Also are you sure your editing the child theme and not the main theme? These are the only two things that I can come up with that result in this behavior if its not a cache.